# Insert Date and a blank line VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

A little bit of background. I've developed a few projects in MS-Access using VBA. Now I have a small project in word that I need to complete. However MSWord is a different ballgame compared to access and I need a little help.

I need to insert the date with Now() (or whatever the equivalent to DATE with exact time) and underneath that a blank line and then a return so you can begin typing underneath the blank line after pressing return. From what I gathered it's pretty hard to capture the enter/return key effectively in msword.

Here's what I have so far. Am I on the right track?

```
Private Sub Document_New(KeyAscii As Integer)
 If KeyAscii = vbKeyEnter Then
  Dim MyText As String
  Dim RN As String
   RN = Now()
   MyText = "_______________________________________________________"
Selection.TypeText (Now())
Selection.TypeText (MyText)
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what your requirment is... Is the user never going to press Enter other than that in this document? Where are you getting the KeyAscii parameter from? What, more specifically, do you need help with? Is the code you show us working? If not, how not?

Comment: The code is not working, I pretty much need a macro that when you press enter you get the current date/time and underneath that a solid line and then another return. I can get the code to send the line and time but not when pressing enter. Basically I want to separate paragraphs with a line and the current time when pressing enter.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in VBA, but it's complex. Almost any key combination can be mapped to a macro using the KeyBindings object. The tricky part is to only have the mappinag work where and when you need it. That involves identifying the events necessaary to trigger mapping back-and-forth. In addition, it's Imperative to identify for which document(s) the remapping should be active and save the remapping correctly so it doesnt affect other documents (CustomizationContext).

There's. Knowledge Base article that describes exactly how to remap the Enter key to a macro. There's other stuff in the article, you need to filter that out and concentrate on the remapping and removing the mapping:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/211219

Quite frankly, I think remapping Enter is not a good approach since it's used for other things. Anotherkey combination would be better and not involve any appreciable effort. If you don't do it just right, you could end up disabling Enter for the entire Word application.